# SBT run differences between scala and java?

Tags: java, scala, sbt, log4j2

I'm trying to follow the [log4j2 configuration tutorials](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/configuration.html) in a SBT 0.12.1 project. Here is my *build.sbt*:

```
name := "Logging Test"

version := "0.0"

scalaVersion := "2.9.2"

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "org.apache.logging.log4j" % "log4j-api" % "2.0-beta3",
  "org.apache.logging.log4j" % "log4j-core" % "2.0-beta3"
)
```

I have two separate main classes. The first is `logtest.ScalaTest` in *src/main/scala/logtest/ScalaTest.scala*:

```
package logtest

import org.apache.logging.log4j.{Logger, LogManager}

object ScalaTest {
  private val logger = LogManager.getLogger(getClass())
  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    logger.trace("Entering application.")
    val bar = new Bar()
    if (!bar.doIt())
      logger.error("Didn't do it.")

    logger.trace("Exiting application.")
  }
}
```

and the second is `logtest.JavaTest` in *src/main/java/logtest/JavaTest.java*:

```
package logtest;

import org.apache.logging.log4j.Logger;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager;

public class JavaTest {
  private static Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger(JavaTest.class.getName());

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    logger.trace("Entering application.");
    Bar bar = new Bar();

    if (!bar.doIt())
      logger.error("Didn't do it.");

    logger.trace("Exiting application.");
  }
}
```

If I run `logtest.ScalaTest.main()`  from inside sbt I get the output I was expecting given that *src/main/resources/log4j2.xml* sets the root logging level to trace:

```
> run-main logtest.ScalaTest
[info] Running logtest.ScalaTest 
10:26:23.730 [run-main] TRACE logtest.ScalaTest$ - Entering application.
10:26:23.733 [run-main] TRACE logtest.Bar -  entry
10:26:23.733 [run-main] ERROR logtest.Bar - Did it again!
10:26:23.733 [run-main] TRACE logtest.Bar -  exit with (false)
10:26:23.733 [run-main] ERROR logtest.ScalaTest$ - Didn't do it.
10:26:23.733 [run-main] TRACE logtest.ScalaTest$ - Exiting application.
[success] Total time: 0 s, completed Dec 21, 2012 10:26:23 AM
```

However, when I run  `logtest.JavaTest.main()` from inside sbt I get different output

```
> run-main logtest.JavaTest
[info] Running logtest.JavaTest 
ERROR StatusLogger Unable to locate a logging implementation, using SimpleLogger
ERROR Bar Did it again!
ERROR JavaTest Didn't do it.
[success] Total time: 0 s, completed Dec 21, 2012 10:27:29 AM
```

From what I can tell, `ERROR StatusLogger Unable to ...` is usually a sign that log4j-core is not on my classpath. The lack of TRACE messages seems to indicate that my log4j2.xml settings aren't on the classpath either. Why should there be any difference in classpath if I'm running Foo.main versus LoggerTest.main? Or is there something else causing this behavior?

### Update

I used SBT Assembly to build a fat jar of this project and specified logtest.JavaTest to be the main class. Running it from the command line produced correct results:

```
$ java -jar "Logging Test-assembly-0.0.jar" 
10:29:41.089 [main] TRACE logtest.JavaTest - Entering application.
10:29:41.091 [main] TRACE logtest.Bar -  entry
10:29:41.091 [main] ERROR logtest.Bar - Did it again!
10:29:41.091 [main] TRACE logtest.Bar -  exit with (false)
10:29:41.091 [main] ERROR logtest.JavaTest - Didn't do it.
10:29:41.091 [main] TRACE logtest.JavaTest - Exiting application.
```

## GitHub Example

Following Edmondo1984's suggestion, I put together a complete example and put it up on [github](https://github.com/ecartner/sbt-run-log).

Comment: how are you running the two programs?

Comment: In the first cases I was using `$ sbt run` and then picking which main class to run when prompted by sbt.

Comment: Sorry if that wasn't real clear. My "second case" was what I mentioned in my Update. Thus I would run `$ sbt assembly` and then `$ java -jar "Logging Test-assembly-0.0.jar"`.

Comment: Still confused: case 1. sbt run, case 2 java classfile from the command line, case 2 modified, fat jar?

Comment: Again, forgive me I'm horrible at conveying my thoughts sometimes! Let me try a different explanation. I've got three basic tests. #1 from inside sbt `> run-main logtest.Foo` - this runs the scala main and produces correct results. #2 again, inside sbt ` > run-main logtest.LoggerTest` - this runs the java main and produces the bad results. #3 two parts: a) from inside sbt `> assembly` - this produces the "fat jar" and b) from shell `$ java -jar "Logging Test-assembly-0.0.jar"` - this runs the main class designated in _build.sbt_ by `mainClass in assembly := ...`.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/21521/discussion-between-quigibo-and-edmondo1984)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These kind of issues are very often due to class-loading difference and in this case the difference is non trivial.

During this initialization phase, the `LogManager` static initializer is called when the class is firstly loaded. If you look inside the static initializer you will see:

```
        Enumeration<URL> enumResources = null;
        try {
            enumResources = cl.getResources(LOGGER_RESOURCE);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            logger.fatal("Unable to locate " + LOGGER_RESOURCE, e);
        }
```

Later in the code, you will see a loop over the enum resources to create the logger context factory.

However, when you run the Scala class `enumResources.hasMoreElements()` returns **true**, while when you run the java class it returns **false** (so no logger context and no loggers are added at all to the LogManager).

If you investigate further, you will see that the `cl` variable is in fact a class loader, which in case of the Java class is an instance of `sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader` while for the Scala class is an instance `sbt.classpath.ClasspathUtilities$$anon$1`

If you look at the beginning of the static initializer, you will see that the following statement:

```
 static {
        // Shortcut binding to force a specific logging implementation.
        PropsUtil managerProps = new PropsUtil("log4j2.LogManager.properties");
        String factoryClass = managerProps.getStringProperty(FACTORY_PROPERTY_NAME);
        ClassLoader cl = findClassLoader();
```

So you might want to have a look to the `findClassLoader()` method:

```
private static ClassLoader findClassLoader() {
            ClassLoader cl;
            if (System.getSecurityManager() == null) {
                cl = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader();
            } else {
                cl = java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(
                    new java.security.PrivilegedAction<ClassLoader>() {
                        public ClassLoader run() {
                            return Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader();
                        }
                    }
                );
            }
            if (cl == null) {
                cl = LogManager.class.getClassLoader();
            }

            return cl;
        }
```

In both case, since the SecurityManager is not null, it returns the current Thread context class loader. Which is different for your Java class and your Scala class.

Comment: it would be interesting however to know why the Java Class loader is not able to load the xml configuration when running from sbt